# Nvidia and Bumblebee

Tags: xorg, nvidia, intel-graphics, optimus

Good morning,

I own an Asus ux501jw PC with Optimus technology, and the problem is that I can't get Bumblebees to work. ([I followed the Fedora WIki's instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee)) and I get this error:

```
[bruno@linux-2 home]$ optirun -b none nvidia-settings -c :8
[ 1994.331811] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
```

My configuration:

Linux version: Fedora 28 (Gnome 3)

```
[root@linux-2 ~]# lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [10de:139b] (rev a2)
```

Nvidia xorg conf:

```
[root@linux-2 xorg.conf.d]# cat 10-nvidia.conf 
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
    Option "SLI" "Auto"
    Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib64/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "intel"
    MatchDriver "i915"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection
```

I added this in the kernel options:

**acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows\ 2009**

My grub configuration file:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau rhgb quiet acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows\ 2009""
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I finally managed to make it all work by following this documentation -> https://www.linux.ncsu.edu/bumblebee#closed-fedora. For example to launch a game on the nvidia card I use the command: primusrun %command%